# One event sub for multiple textboxes instead of declaring it multiple time?

Tags: vba

Is it possible to have one change event procedure for multiple textboxes in the same workbook?
If for example, I have a textbox named "textbox3" in the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd sheet of the workbook and I would like this single code below to work for all of them (the textboxes) rather than having to declare it on each sheet. Right now, I have to declare the same procedure on all the sheets but I only want to declare it once since it does the same thing on all of them.

```
'my procedure
Sub testObj()
Dim i As Integer, obj As oleobject
Set ac = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

For Each obj In ac.oleobjects
    If TypeName(obj.Object) = "TextBox" And obj.name = "TextBox3" Then
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve TextArray(1 To i)
        Set TextArray(i).TextBoxEvents = obj
    End If
Next obj
Set obj = Nothing
```

End Sub

```
'My class1
Public WithEvents TextBoxEvents As MSForms.TextBox
'Public WithEvents TextBoxEvents As OLEObject
 

Private Sub TextBoxEvents_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyTab Then
        TextBox12.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Declare it in a module instead, make sure it's public instead of private, and then pass the textbox control to it as an argument from each form's event.

Comment: Typically you'd use a *control array* for something like this: see for example http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/

Comment: Would your advice work on worksheets? These textboxes are not on forms

Comment: It works the same way as on forms.  FYI if you want to flag me with a question then you can include `@TimWilliams` and I'll get a notification...

Comment: @TimWilliams ,  I have not been able to get it to work on a worksheet. Might you have an example that could show it?

Comment: If you post the code you tried I will take a look.

Comment: @TimWilliams I did it like this above but wasn't able to bind the procedure to the textbox event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example

Class module named `clsTextBox`:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents TextBoxEvents As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub TextBoxEvents_Change()
    Debug.Print TextBoxEvents.Name & ": " & TextBoxEvents.Text
End Sub

'Private Sub TextBoxEvents_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
'    If KeyCode = vbKeyTab Then
'        TextBox12.Activate 'unclear what you're aiming for here?
'    End If
'End Sub
```

Regular module:

```vb
Dim ColTB As Collection

Sub testObj()
    Dim i As Integer, obj As OLEObject, ac As Worksheet
    
    Set ac = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set ColTB = New Collection
    For Each obj In ac.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(obj.Object) = "TextBox" Then
            ColTB.Add EventObj(obj.Object)
        End If
    Next obj
    Set obj = Nothing
End Sub

Function EventObj(obj As MSForms.TextBox) As clsTextBox
    Dim o As New clsTextBox
    Set o.TextBoxEvents = obj
    Set EventObj = o
End Function
```

Comment: Not sure what's going on, tried to test it and I get userdefined type not defined with  Function EventObj(obj As MSForms.TextBox) As clsTextBox

Comment: Did you name the Class module "clsTextBox"?  Do you have a reference in your VBA project to  "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library" ? (you can get that by adding a userform to your project and then removing it - the reference will remain)

Comment: Oh I named it class1